# number of images for training YOLOv3 on custom dataset

Tags: object-detection

I going to train YOLOv3 on my own custom dataset following the instructions found on the Darknet github repo: 
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects

I have so far manually labeled 300 images per object class and I want to ask what is the minimum number of labeled images per class needed to have a good model performance?( as the manual labeling takes much time )